# Send SQL Query output to email using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to send SQL query output to email using PowerShell, how can I do this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
$query =  select name, surname, gender, accountNumber from table1
$Report = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "instance" -Database "db2" -Query $query

$MailUsername = "mail"
$MailPassword = "1234"
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($MailUsername,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $MailPassword -AsPlainText -Force))
Send-MailMessage -To "me@yahoo.com" -From "you@yahoo.com" -SmtpServer mail.net -Credential $cred -Subject "weekly Report:" -Body "$Report"
```

I want to be able to send the report in form of a table or something that looks nice? How can I do that?

My code above is running into errors, can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an attachment was all I needed, please see below:

```
 $message = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
            $message.From = $fromaddress
            $message.To.Add($toaddress)
            $message.CC.Add($CCaddress)
            $message.Bcc.Add($bccaddress)
            $message.IsBodyHtml = $True
            $message.Subject = $Subject
            $attach = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachment)
            $message.Attachments.Add($attach)
            $message.body = $body
            $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpserver)
            $smtp.Send($message)
```